# Conditional to the caption property of a popupmenu item

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have a popupmenu with a item named "Ativar", but i can not understand why this code don't work:

```
procedure TForm6.Ativar1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ativar1.Caption='Ativar' then
  begin
    showmessage('Initialize procedure');
    ativar1.Caption:='Desativar';
  end else
  if ativar1.Caption='Desativar' then
  begin
    showmessage('Initialize procedure');
    ativar1.Caption:='Ativar';
  end;
end;
```

I imagine that writing code should do the verification of the caption property of the object to activate if it is equal to Enable show the message and change the caption property to Disable, yet when the caption property is equal to Disable show the message and change the property again to Enable. What is wrong?

Comment: You should not keep state in the caption of a UI component. What if it ever gets translated? Or if you change your mind and make the caption longer in the object inspector? Then your logic will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not keep state in the caption of a UI component. What if it ever gets translated? Or if you change your mind and make the caption longer in the object inspector? Then your logic will fail.

It is better to do something like this:

- move the state away from the `Caption` into a separate form field (I prefer enumerated types over booleans, so the statefield is `FAtivarState` and the type is `TAtivarState`)
- to make sure you can translate your application, move your initial `Ativar` value `Caption` for `Ativar1` from the Object Inspector to a [resourcestring](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Declared_Constants#Resource_Strings), and one for the `desactivar` state (note I kept the `A` keyboard shortcut for both)
  if you do not need to translate, then you can replace `resourcestring` with `const`
- separate the assignment of the caption and the business logic into two methods (`SetAtivarCaption` and `HandleAtivarChange`)
- call these methods from the `FormCreate` event method (bind it to the `OnCreate` event of `TForm6`) and `Ativar1Click` event method

A structured approach like the above looks like a lot of extra work, but it isn't: it saves you a lot of time solving problems like you had in your question.

Example code:

```
// unit name, interface clause, uses list, etc ...

type
  TAtivarState = (asAtivar, asDesativar);
  TForm6 = class(TForm);
    procedure Ativar1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FAtivarState: TAtivarState;
    procedure SetAtivarCaption(); virtual; 
    procedure HandleAtivarChange(); virtual; 

// implementation clause, uses list, etc ...

resourcestring
  AtivarCaption = '&Ativar';
  DestivarCaption = 'Des&ativar';

procedure TForm6.Ativar1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HandleAtivarChange();
end;

procedure TForm6.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetActivar1Caption();
end;

procedure TForm6.SetAtivarCaption();
begin
  if FAtivarState = asAtivar then
    Ativar1.Caption := AtivarCaption
  else
    Ativar1.Caption := DesativarCaption;
end;

procedure TForm6.HandleAtivarChange();
begin
  if FAtivarState = asAtivar then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Initialize procedure');
    FAtivarState := asDesativar;
  end
  else
  begin
    ShowMessage('Initialize procedure');
    FAtivarState := asAtivar;
  end;
  SetActivar1Caption();
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I will delve into in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

Use `StripHotKey` vom Menues to replace the accelerator.

```
begin
  if StripHotKey(TMenuItem(Sender).Caption) = 'Ativar' then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Initialize procedure');
    TMenuItem(Sender).Caption := 'Desativar';
  end
  else if StripHotKey(TMenuItem(Sender).Caption) = 'Desativar' then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Initialize procedure');
    TMenuItem(Sender).Caption := 'Ativar';
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

thats becouse if you show message the caption you will see instead of 'Ativar' the '&Ativar' string, so both of your tests fail,

well you could add the '&' to your tests but i strongly suggest you use other property like tag instead, or the checked property depending on what ur doing

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, and this one works perfectly. Jut add an '&' to your condition checking:

```
procedure TForm6.Ativar1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if ativar1.Caption='&Ativar' then
begin
  showmessage('Initialize procedure');
  ativar1.Caption:='Desativar';
end else
if ativar1.Caption='&Desativar' then
begin
  showmessage('Initialize procedure');
  ativar1.Caption:='Ativar';
end;

end;
```